# How does one come to own a phoenix as a pet?

Tags: harry-potter

Any sources pertaining to how Dumbledore came to acquire Fawkes as a loyal pet?

Comment: The words "loyal" and "pet" indicate that you seek two different stories, neither of which I have the time or inclination to recite to you now.

Comment: Why do you think Fawkes is a Pet? I've cared for a few strays, feeding them and tending the occasional wound. They usually show you loyalty and may even be willing to come inside - especially when the weather turns cold - they are rarely tamed.

Comment: Some people also believe that Fawkes is actually a Horcrux which explains the loyalty of Fawkes (which is quite similar to the loyalty of Nagini).